# MSSQL Group by and Select rows from grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out if what I'm trying to do is possible. Instead of resorting to multiple queries on a table, I wanted to group the records by business date and id then group by the id and select one date for a field and another date for the other field.

```
SELECT
    *
    {AMOUNT FROM DATE}
    {AMOUNT FROM OTHER DATE}
FROM (
    SELECT 
        date, 
        id,
        SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM
        table
    GROUP BY id, date 
AS subquery
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Can you please add some sample data with expected output from them?

Comment: Sample data and expected result, please. It doesn't look difficult, but your explanation is not clear enough yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're looking to do a pivot query. I usually use cross tabs for this. Based on the query you posted, it could look like:

```
SELECT
    id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date = '20190901' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AmountFromSept01,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date = '20191001' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AmountFromOct01
FROM (
    SELECT 
        date, 
        id,
        SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM
        table
    GROUP BY id, date 
    )AS subquery
GROUP BY id;
```

You could also use a CTE.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT 
        date, 
        id,
        SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM
        table
    GROUP BY id, date 
)
SELECT
    id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date = '20190901' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AmountFromSept01,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date = '20191001' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AmountFromOct01
FROM CTE
GROUP BY id;
```

Or even be a rebel and do the operation directly.

```
SELECT
    id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date = '20190901' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AmountFromSept01,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date = '20191001' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AmountFromOct01
FROM CTE
GROUP BY id;
```

However, some people have tested for performance and found that pre-aggregating can improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you're just trying to pivot, but only with two particular dates:

```
select      id,
            date1 = sum(iif(date = '2000-01-01', amount, null)),
            date2 = sum(iif(date = '2000-01-02', amount, null))
from        [table]
group by    id
```